# RDLC An error occurred during local report processing: Scalable List: index 16 outside the allowed range [0::15]

Tags: sql-server

I'm running Visual Studio 2015 and using the build-in report generator and viewer. I just created a report with the wizard and if I run this report and press the print layout button for rendering the page to have a visual feedback, all went fine.
I want to create a running page total on each page. So I added a column to my report with the following expression:

(=Runningvalue(Fields!Totaal.Value,Sum,"Begroting"))

Running the report, press the Print Layout button, all went fine. I can see the running values summing on each line. But now I want to show the running total in my report footer. So I added a textbox with the following expression: =Last(ReportItems!Textbox24.Value), where textbox24 is the column I added. Now I get an error:
An error occurred during local report processing: Scalable List: index 16 outside the allowed range [0::15]
I tried to move the textbox from the footer to the report body but then I get another error:

The Value expression for the textrun 'Textbox34.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' uses an aggregate function on a report item.  Aggregate functions can be used only on report items contained in page headers and footers. BCP C:\Users\Mark\Google Drive\Projects\BCP\BCP\Begroting.rdlc

So in both cases I get an error.
Is there any method or other solution to solve my problem? 
The report is processed locally (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB

Product Microsoft SQL Server Express (64-bit)

Version 13.0.2151.0

Regards

Mark

Comment: You say you want to add the running total to the report footer. However, if you do that, how is that different from just adding an overall total instead?

Comment: Because I need a Running Total, not an Overall Total. An overall total is working just fine, just use the sum function on particular field.